# Уровни исключений и логирование

Tags: php, исключения, логирование, exception-handler

Мне нужно разработать систему интеграции с различными информационными системами.

В процессе разработки будут случаи, когда в непредвиденных ситуациях требуется отправлять уведомления по почте, в других случаях записывать информацию в журнал или отправлять SMS в критических ситуациях.

Для логирования и других уведомлений я выбрал `Monolog` (только знакомлюсь с монологом).

Вопрос в том, как мне организовать работу `Exception`, так, чтобы существовали разные уровни исключений и выполнялись соответствующие действия (запись логов в журнал и т. Д.)?

Я искал информацию в разных источниках, нашел несколько статей о работе с исключениями (статья на [habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/264417/)).

`UnloggedInterface`- все необработанные ошибки регистрируются по умолчанию. Этот интерфейс отмечает, Exceptionsчто не нужно регистрироваться вообще.

`PreloggedInterface` - этот интерфейс помечает исключения, которые в любом случае необходимо регистрировать: не имеет значения, обрабатываются они или нет.

`OutableInterface` - этот интерфейс помечает исключения, текст которых может быть передан пользователю.

Я не понимаю, какой должна быть иерархия наследования Exception классов?
Каким образом нужно связать `Monolog` (или любую другую систему логирования) с классами исключений ?

Может нужно использовать `Monolog\ErrorHandler` ? (но я не знаю как) ..

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я могу посмотреть примеры?
Или где почитать об этом подробнее?

Я хотел бы понять, как это работает.
И посмотрите примеры правильной работы с исключениями и логами.

Можно даже примеры на GitHub))

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Я логирую исключения с помощью ErrorHandler.
Для установки уровня логирования я наследовал \Exception и добавил в него метод, возвращающий LogLevel.

Желательно создать интерфейс, а внутри обработчика ошибок проверять исключение на соответствие интерфейсу. Если подходит, получать уровень с помощью метода, если не подходит - ставить ERROR

```
class WarningException extends \Exception
{
    public function getLogLevel()
    {
        return LogLevel::ERROR;
    }
}
```